# Hibernate Spring: inserting multiple entries at once

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Currently I am struggling with the problem as below:

I have a program that will hold information on the electricity meters and their readings.
I wanted to create a form in which I can insert all the readings for all registered meters at once.
I am currently stuck at this point:

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/registerEnergyReading")
public ModelAndView registerEnergyReading(@ModelAttribute("reading") Reading reading, BindingResult result) {
    List<ElectricityMeter> meters= meterService.getMeterList();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("meters", meters);
    System.out.println("Register Form");
    return new ModelAndView("RegisterEnergyReading", "model", model);}
```

Now the jsp file would create a table dynamically based on how many meters are there. 
That would be done by < c:forEach items="${meters}" var="meters" >

But the tricky part for me is how to pass these multiple entries for the next controller to be saved? What form should be used here?

```
@RequestMapping("/saveReadings")
     public ModelAndView saveReadings(
     @ModelAttribute("reading") List<Reading> reading, BindingResult result) {
    for(Reading i:reading) {
     readingService.saveReading(i);
    }
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/najemcaLista.html");
     }
```

Am I going the right direction here?

Appreciate your help,
Maciej

I got a bit further but got stuck.

My controller looks now:

```
@RequestMapping("/registerEnergyReading")
    public ModelAndView registerEnergyReading(
             @ModelAttribute("listReadingModel") ListReadingModel listReadingModel, BindingResult result) {
        List<EnergyMeter> energyMetersList= meterService.getMeters();

        List<EnergyReading> readings= new ArrayList<EnergyReading>();

        for (int i = 0; i < energyList.size(); i++) {
            EnergyReading reading= new EnergyReading ();
            reading.setMeter(energyList.get(i));
            readings.add(reading);
        }
        listReadingModel.setEnergyReadings(readings);
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("energyMetersList", energyMetersList);
        model.put("readings", readings);
        return new ModelAndView("registerEnergyReading", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/saveEnergyReading")
    public ModelAndView saveEnergyReading(
            @ModelAttribute("listReadingModel") ListReadingModel listReadingModel, BindingResult result) {

        List<EnergyMeter> energyMetersList=listReadingModel.getEnergyReadings()
        for (EnergyReading i : reading) {
            readingService.saveReading(i);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/energyReadingsList.html");
    }
```

here is my view file:

```
<c:url var="listReadingModel" value="listReadingModel.html" />
<form:form id="listReadingModel" modelAttribute="listReadingModel" method="post" action="${listReadingModel}">

<table width="400px" height="150px">

<c:forEach items="${model.readings}" var="readings">
<tr>
<td>${readings.meter.description}</td>
<td><form:label path="${readingValue}">Reading Value</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="${readingValue}" /></td>
<td><form:label path="${readingDate}">date</form:label></td>
<td><form:input type="date" path="${readingDate}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
</table>
        </form:form>
```

'

When I open the page in browser it all looks ok (there are as many fields as there should be) but when I press "save" I get java.lang.NullPointerException. It seems the form doesn't pass listReadingModel to controller. Any ideas how to solve it? Appologies for any typos. The code is in different language so I translated it on the go.

Regards, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I think what you need is to create a wrapper class as

```
public class ListReadingModel {

    private List<Reading> readings;

    // Getter, setter
}
```

And then under your registerEnergyReading method, add this ListReadingModel to your Model.

```
ListReadingModel listReadingModel = new ListReadingModel ();
model.put("listReadingModel", listReadingModel);
```

You can bind your ListReadingModel to your form element in the jsp file.

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="listReadingModel">
// add meters and readings here
```

When submitted your jsp you can call your controller like that:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveReadings")
public ModelAndView saveReadings(
    @ModelAttribute("listReadingModel") ListReadingModel listReadingModel , BindingResult result) {

    List<Reading> reading = listReadingModel.getReadings();
    for(Reading i:reading) {
         readingService.saveReading(i);
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/najemcaLista.html");
}
```

This can work but I did not try it. You can search named wrapper class on google to find more information.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!